# How to query on a Mysql cursor?

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

I have fetched data into mysql cursor now i want to sum up a column in the cursor.
Is there any BIF or any thing i can do to make it work ?

```
db = cursor.execute("SELECT api_user.id, api_user.udid, api_user.ps, api_user.deid, selldata.lid, api_selldata.sells
FROM api_user
INNER JOIN api_user.udid=api_selldata.udid AND api_user.pc='com'")
```

Comment: please plaace the edited as after edit

Comment: which columns u need to sum. use sum(columnname)

Comment: i need sum of this column api_selldata.sells. I tried doing so  with sum(api_selldata.sells) but it's not working for me :\

Comment: "Not working" as in you get an error message, or as in you get the wrong result? The more information you give, the more likely someone can help, so please report the current results.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is that you can't include aggregate functions such as SUM() in a query unless you can guarantee (usually by adding a GROUP BY clause) that the values of the non-aggregated columns are the same for all rows included in the SUM().

The aggregate functions effectively condense a column over many rows into a single value, which cannot be done for non-aggregated columns unless SQL knows that they are guaranteed to have the same value for all considered rows (which a GROUP BY will do, but this may not be what you want).

Comment: yeah right !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606009/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-a-column-in-an-sql-table-for-a-given-date-and-patchi

This answer solved my problem. Thank you all for helping